# How to merge csv files using batch

Tags: csv, batch-file, vbscript, merge, xls

I have to merge some .csv files into one .xls file using batch. 
The problem is that I have to take the .csv file column by column and put in the .xls file like that. 
Can I do this using a batch or do you have some better suggestion? I should specify that there are two columns in every file and one of them is text and the other decimal number. 
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Besides the fact that you did not show any own efforts, which makes it off-topic as request-my-code question, it is not quite clear: How is the data to be merged? do you want to append the next CSV file as new rowns, or as new columns? if the latter applies, do they all have the same number of rows? if not, how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question needs a bit more work. An XLS file is an Excel formatted binary file. As used by Excel 97 - 2003.

Renaming a file from *.CSV to *.XLS does not make it an Excel file, even though the icon might change and Excel will open it, it's still just a text file.  I'd be surprised if you had a batch file that converts a text file with commas to an Excel file. As the easiest way to do the conversion would be to open the CSV in Excel and save it as an XLS file.

So the question might be, how can I combine multiple CSV files into one?

In which case you can use copy and "+", e.g the following copies four CSV files into OUTPUT.CSV

`copy text1.csv + text2.csv + text3.csv + text4.csv OUTPUT.CSV`

The problem with this if the CSV files have headings then those are also combined so you'll get the subsequent headings mixed in with the data.

More details please?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answer! Actually, I had to edit and merge some CSV files that export results from Ansys, into a new .txt or .xls file. I solved it by writing a batch file which edit the .csv one by one and then put the content into a .txt. Thank you!